# GWT i18n with properties from database

Tags: gwt, internationalization

Is there any way to load properties from database with i18n standards.?

*In existing method,*

- it loads properties from properties files.

  html entities are escaped by default.

  if I want to change a property, I need to restart the server every time for the changes to reflect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set text using data from the database instead of properties files. Before you do that, however, consider the drawbacks:

- You have to write the code to retrieve each value from a database, because the value is not known at compile time.
- You do not know if you missed any of the properties, because the properties are not compiled. If you did miss a property, your users will not any text for it.
- Your app will have to make many more calls to the server in order to display each view, which can dramatically slow down your app. You can partially mitigate this by using JSP to dynamically generate key-value pairs using [dynamic string i18n](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideI18n.html#DevGuideDynamicStringInternationalization), but the load time will still be slower than with static i18n.

This is why I have never seen this done.

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir,  
Taking values from database is an option.
But even if I take value from properties file, I have the below problem.  
I can't able to use unicode characters in property values, because HTML characters are escaped by default.
For example, the text I need the value வணக்கம் from properties, so I'm adding the below text in properties file (for Tamil (ta)),  
   &#2997;&#2979;&#2965;&#3021;&#2965;&#2990;&#3021;
But it's not showing as வணக்கம், it is showing as it is (since the HTML characters are escaped by default).  
How can I prevent it.

Comment: If you use UTF8 for your property files and set UTF8 your environment when you compile it should work. GWT i18n source files are plenty of non ascii characters and they are in utf8. Anyway if you prefer your property files in ascii, you have to use unicode (\u2990)  instead of html escaping (&#2990;)

Comment: Install ResourceBundle editor in Eclipse, if you are not using it already. Then open your properties files in this editor.

Comment: When using \u2990, it give the output like "⦐" (an unknown character).  
Also tried with ResourceBundle editor, its just replacing \u2990 with \\u2990.  
What I need is, is there any option to disable escaping HTML characters?

Comment: In ResourceBundle editor you should type or paste your text in Tamil (after you set the encoding to UTF-8).